# Is @supports available in LESS / Edge specific CSS rules written in LESS

Tags: css, less, visual-studio-2017, microsoft-edge

Edge doesn't support styling above this section (no support for clip-path current) so to fix the styling I am trying to write Edge specific CSS.

I'm using LESS and I get an error when I try to to compile because it thinks that `@supports` is a LESS function. LESS will however recognise that `@media` is the CSS method.

My question is, how do I make the following code work with LESS or is there a better way to write Edge only CSS

```
@supports (-ms-ime-align:auto) {
    .section {
        padding-top: 0px !important;
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
The issue appears to be with Visual Studios LESS compiler not recognising `@supports`

Comment: That shouldn't be happening. What version of LESS are you using?

Comment: Tried to quickly replicate this and it seems to work fine http://jsbin.com/zorivadiza/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Top example, and thank you for the response. It appears that it may be Visual Studios LESS compiler that doesn't support it

Comment: Should be safe to post as an answer, unless there's something else you're looking for.

Comment: It's the answer to the question I posted. I'll have to ask a second question to work out why it's not work in Visual Studio

Answer (score 1):

You are hopefully long-done with this project, but you can force LESS to not pre-process with the tilde and single quotes:

```
 @supports ~'(-ms-ime-align:auto)' {
    .section {
        padding-top: 0px !important;
    }
}
```

This renders to css as intended using the current Visual Studio 2019 - Web Compiler

Comment: Thanks for the workaround ! Actually latest build of VS 2019 and web compiler work even without the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I think less, at least for the version I am working on, cannot render `@support` tag inside a hierarchy.
So I struggled to make something like this work:

```
#header {
  // some CSS...

  @supports (-webkit-mask-image: url()) or (mask-image: url()) {
    i {
      -webkit-mask-size: cover;
      mask-size: cover;
    }
  }
}
```

And finally, I make it by moving the whole hierarchy inside `@support` tag like this. A bit of repetition, yet it will do.

```
#header {
  // some CSS...
}
@supports (-webkit-mask-image: url()) or (mask-image: url()) {
  #header {
    i {
      -webkit-mask-size: cover;
      mask-size: cover;
    }
  }
}
```